# Troubles with accessing property in derivied class

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    protected readonly List<Node> Nodes = new List<Node>();
    public Node[] ChildNodes => Nodes.ToArray();
    ...
}
```

And derived from him:

```
public sealed class NodeArray<T> : Node where T: Node
{
    private readonly List<T> _array = new List<T>(); 
    private new List<Node> Nodes => _array.Cast<Node>().ToList();
    public new Node[] ChildNodes => _array.Cast<Node>().ToArray();
    ...
}
```

Node.Nodes list may contain NodeArray<Smth> through.
But, when I'm trying to recursively enumerate nodes, and I'm getting one of type NodeArray, it returns empty ChildNodes value (of base class I guess). 
And when I debugged following code, Intellisense shows two identical properties with the same name and same type!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otnv8.png)

Loop code:

```
protected void LoadNode(Node node, XmlNode xmlNode)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in xmlNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (childNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                var child = node.ChildNodes.First(p => p.Name == childNode.Name);  // <----- Stuck here
                if(child == null)
                    throw new Exception("Unknown child " + childNode.Name + " in Node " + node.Name);

                LoadNode(child, childNode);
            }
            else
            {
                node[childNode.Name] = childNode.Value;
            }
        }

        node.Load();
    }
```

Hope you help! Sorry for bed English :)

Comment: why is NodeArray generic? , given that it always contains Node objects.

Comment: nodearray and node both have a member called Nodes. Did you mean that?

Comment: >why is NodeArray generic?

For easier access inside the parent class (without having to cast it to derived class on every access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be that you're using member hiding (with the `new` keyword) rather than overriding. With member hiding, the base class and the derived class contain separate definitions of the property, despite having the same name. Thus, if you create a `NodeArray<T>` instance, populate its `_array` collection, and then pass it as a `Node` reference, then `ChildNodes` property would still be returning the empty collection of the `Node.Nodes` base property, rather than the `NodeArray<T>._array` field like you'd expect.

To resolve this issue, switch to using virtual and overridden members, as shown below:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    protected virtual List<Node> Nodes { get; } = new List<Node>();
    public virtual Node[] ChildNodes => Nodes.ToArray();
    ...
}

public sealed class NodeArray<T> : Node where T: Node
{
    private readonly List<T> _array = new List<T>(); 
    protected override List<Node> Nodes => _array.Cast<Node>().ToList();
    public override Node[] ChildNodes => _array.Cast<Node>().ToArray();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to override property without making it `virtual` in a base class. Thanks!